# WaitForSingleObjectによるバッチファイルの終了待ちについて

Tags: windows, c++, mfc, batch-file

開発PC：Windows XP＋VC6
実行PC：Windows XP or Windows7

MFCで作られたアプリからバッチファイルをモーダルで実行してバッチファイルの終了待ちをしたいと考えています。

バッチファイルは末尾に「pause」を入れて何らかのキー入力かウィンドウを閉じることで
終了とします。

・バッチファイル実行部

```
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo ;
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo ;

GetStartupInfo(&siStartInfo);

if(!CreateProcess(NULL,
                "[cmd.exeのフルパス] /c [バッチファイルのフルパス]",
                NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,           
                NULL, NULL,
                &siStartInfo,
                &piProcInfo)){
    return FALSE;
}

WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
```

・バッチファイルの中身

```
@echo off
echo TestTest
pause
```

WaitForSingleObjectで終了待ちをしているのですが、
WindowsXP上で実行すると、プロンプト画面でキーの入力＆ウィンドウ終了が出来ますが、
同じアプリをWindows7で実行すると、プロンプト画面でキーの入力もウィンドウの終了も出来ません。

WindowsXPとWindows7とで、WaitForSingleObjectの挙動が変わったのでしょうか？

■2015/06/05追記
下記の様にしたら出来ました。

```
while(WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,100) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
    app->PumpMessage();     // 定期的にメッセージキューを消化させます
}
```

メッセージが処理されていなかったようです。

Comment: 症状から推測するに`WaitForSingleObject`の問題ではなく、`CreateProcess`でのプロセス起動オプションの問題の可能性もあります。`siStartInfo`への設定値も正確に示されたほうが、問題解決につながるかもしれません。

Comment: yohjpさん  ありがとうございます。siStartInfoに設定しているのは上記が全てになります。GetStartupInfo関数でsiStartInfoに情報を設定しています。  GetStartupInfo実行後のsiStartInfo中身ということでしょうか？

Comment: GetStartupInfoで取得した親プロセスの情報を、そのまま子プロセス(cmd.exe)起動に渡しているのですね。この値がWinXPと7で変化した可能性がありますから、具体的な設定値を確認すると何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: XPと７でGetStartupInfo実行後のsiStartInfo中身を比較してみましたが、完全に一致しました。XPと７で同じ事が問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: 手元で簡易確認してみましたが、VC2012＋Win7で作ったアプリでは事象再現しませんでした（キー入力できる）。あとは`DETACHED_PROCESS`, `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`フラグを設定するくらいでしょうかね…  MFCアプリということも影響する可能性があるので、質問文面を修正／mfcタグ復活しました。（"違う"のであれば訂正おねがいします）

Comment: 確認頂き、ありがとうございました。私の方でも本機能をアプリ単体で行った場合、問題ありませんでした。今回はDLLで上記のコードを実行しています。DLLだと何か制限があるのでしょうか？

Comment: キー待ちが出ないとの事ですが、Windows7 の場合は実際に起動しているのでしょうか？バッチの中に `echo test > %TEMP%\test.out` 等として、起動後に `test.out` が出ているか確認する事が出来ます。

Comment: メッセージを処理する必要があるスレッドではMsgWaitForMultipleObjects を使うべきではありませんか？

Comment: ひとつも回答がない状態ではシステム上「未解決」として扱われてしまうため、もしよろしければ、解決策を質問に追記する代わりに、ご自身で回答として投稿、承認（回答の左側にあるチェックマーク）していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決の方法を知りませんでした。
教えて頂き、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の様にすることで対策しました。

```
while(WaitForSingleObject(piProcInfo.hProcess,100) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
    app->PumpMessage();     // 定期的にメッセージキューを消化させます
}
```